# C++ Linked List Deletion

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a singly Linked List which has a pointer to its next Node and data(which is a pointer to an object). My question is that when I delete a Node of the linked list only using delete will the object that the Node was pointing to be also automatically  deleted or will i get a dangling pointer. Will the Destructor the object come in play here?

Comment: Nothing is deleted automatically. For each `new` you have, you need to spell out `delete` somewhere. Having said that, a node having a pointer to data is not how containers are usually built in C++. The node normally contains the data itself and not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the answer is no: the data your node points to will not be deleted automatically when you `delete node`, because there is no rule in C++ to do it. But if the destructor of your `Node` class calls `delete data`, then the data will be deleted. You can do the following to check it: implement destructor for your data object class or put a breakpoint in existing destructor and then debug code that calls `delete node`. If you need the data to be destroyed when you delete the node, make sure the `Node` destructor calls `delete data`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
class Data 
{
  public: ~Data() 
  { // set a breakpoint on this line or check console output
    std::cout << "data destructor is called...";
  }
};
class Node 
{
  Data* data;
  Node* next;
public: 
  Node() {}
  Node(Data* _data):data(_data) {}
  ~Node() 
  {
    // delete data when the node is deleted
    delete data;
  }
};
int main() {
    std::cout << "create node...";
    Node* node = new Node();
    std::cout << "delete node...";
    delete node;
    std::cout << "deleted node." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "create node with data...";
    Node* nodeWithData = new Node(new Data());
    std::cout << "delete node with data...";
    delete nodeWithData;
    std::cout << "deleted node with data.";

    return 0;
}
```

The sample code is just to illustrate the relation between deleting node and deleting data object.

EDIT 9/27/2023:
Removed if(data) before delete data per viraltaco_'s suggestion in comments. Added sample main() method that creates and then deletes nodes. When the program runs you should get the following output:

```
create node...delete node...deleted node.
create node with data...delete node with data...data destructor is called...deleted node with data.
```

Comment: That if statement does nothing. `delete nullptr;` is valid.

Comment: @viraltaco_, agreed and will update the sample code in the answer